# open files from another directory from python in linux

Tags: python, linux

I have a file in `Linux` called `testing.txt`.

Below is my project structure in `Linux`

```
main_project
├── base_dir
│   └── helper
│       └── file_helper.py
│       └── __init__.py
    └── jobs
        └── adhoc_job.py
        └── __init__.py

        └── test_job.py
        └── __init__.py     

├── share_dir
│   └── testing.txt     

├── scripts
│   └── python_wrapper.sh
```

`Run mechanism`

```
1) Using python_wrapper.sh I will run the `jobs/test_job.py` script. 
2) In jobs/test_job.py I have from helper.file_helper import *
3) In helper/file_helper.py I will read the testing.txt file
```

`helper/file_helper.py contents`

```
print(os.getcwd())

with open("main_project/share_dir/testing.txt") as f:
    data = {}
    for line in f:
        key,value = line.strip().split('#')
        data[key] = value
```

When I call the `python_wrapper.sh` like below I do not have any issues

```
sh /home/$USER/main_project/scripts/python_wrapper.sh test_job
```

When I call the `python_wrapper.sh` like below

```
# change directory to main_project(this is not in python_wrapper.sh)
cd main_project

# run the scripts
sh scripts/python_wrapper.sh test_job
```

Then I am getting `NO file or directory main_project/share_dir/testing.txt error`

I want to read the `testing.txt` file without any issues when calling the `python_wrapper.sh` from any directory

How can I resolve this issue

Comment: Do you understand why you're getting this error?  Your current directory is `main_project`, and you're trying to open a `main_project` from inside there.  You need to decide what the "rule" is.  If the rule is that the current directory is always above `main_project`, then you need to remove the `cd` from `python_wrapper.sh`.  If you want the script to handle being started from anywhere, then you need to construct the path.  I'll put that in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This starts from the file's own location (inside helper) and constructs the actual location of `main_project`:

```
mainproj = os.path.realpath( os.path.dirname(__file__)+"/../.." )
with open( mainproj + "/share_dir/testing.text") as f:
```